# Docker Compose Entry Point File

Tags: docker

I have a docker compose file and want to install maven inside nimbus container once the container is created. I added docker-entrypoint.sh file to compose image but not sure if this is the write way to override entrypoint file

**docker-compose file**

```
image: storm:2.1.0
container_name: nimbus
entrypoint: /docker-entrypoint.sh
```

**docker-entrypoint.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e
# fi
#install nano 
apt update
apt install nano
#install ping
apt-get install iputils-ping
#installmaven 
apt install maven
exec "$@"
```

Comment: Generally you’d install software in a Dockerfile, so it can get installed once at build time, instead of having to repeat the installation steps every time you start the container.  There’s also a potential issue in what you show if the upstream image has its own `ENTRYPOINT` declaration, you need to know what that is and invoke it.

Comment: i want to install maven inside container using docker-entrypoint.sh file

Answer (score 1):

Create a Dockerfile

```
FROM image: storm:2.1.0
RUN apt update
RUN apt install nano
RUN apt-get install iputils-ping
RUN apt install maven
```

Build image using this docker file :

```
docker build -t image-1:v1 -f Dockerfile .
```

Use this image name in your docker compose file :

```
image: image-1:v1
container_name: nimbus
```